# ERROR : The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In my model

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name="Event Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    //[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true ,DataFormatString="{0:DD/MM/YYYY}")]
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
```

in my View (Create.cshtml)

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EventDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EventDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EventDate)
    </div>
```

in Shared/EditorTemplates/Date.cshtml

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", Model.ToShortDateString()),
  new { @class = "datefield", type = "date" })
```

and getting following error

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'.
```

Comment: What does your controller look like that is passing the model to the view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

thanks Solved it with.... just putting the script in the file..

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>



@{
     DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
 if (Model != null)
 {
     dt = (System.DateTime)Model;

 }
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", dt.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "datefield", type = "date" })
} 

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".datefield").datepicker({
            //      buttonImage: "/content/images/calendar.gif",
            //      showOn: "both",
            //      defaultDate: $("#calendar-inline").attr('rel')

            showAnim: 'slideDown',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

try defining your `EventDate` as nullable Type: `DateTime?`

Comment: did but getting compilation error for using Model.ToShortDateString()


CS1061: 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'ToShortDateString' and no extension method 'ToShortDateString' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `if (Model.HasValue) Model.Value.ToShortDateString()`

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to use `DateTime?` as the model, and handle the null value directly.

On nullable types, you call `.HasValue` to see if the value is actually null, or use `??`.  This is how some of my setup code works:

```
// get the date the editor will work with, or use today's date if it is null
DateTime workingDate = if (Model.HasValue) ? Model.Value : DateTime.Now;

// check the model metadata to see if the underlying model type was nullable or not
bool isNullable = ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType;

// get the min date passed in as optional params.  default to some reasonable timeframe
var minDate = ViewBag.MinDate ?? DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)

// now start drawing the editor
```

[This blog post](http://mgolchin.net/posts/21/dive-deep-into-mvc-modelmetadata-and-modelmetadataprovider) is a handy place to start reading about some of of the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Although its a wrong time question but i have another approach. You can create a constructor on your model and initialize date property with some values lets say todays date. Then on your action method create from your controller you can pass a new instance of your model as a parameter on return view statement.